# private variables and property in python

Tags: python

I am messing around with the property descriptor in python, but an interesting error (at least for me) popped up (recursionerror).This is the code that caused it

```
class Employer:

    def __init__(self, age, name):
        self.age = age
        self.name = name

    def get_age(self):
        return self.age

    def set_age(self, value):
        if value > 30:
            raise ValueError("Our company doesn't want old people")
        self.age = value

    def deleter(self):
        del self.age

    age = property(get_age, set_age, deleter)


emp = Employer(20, "Alex")
```

Now, after I changed self.age in the setter method to self._age and did the same thing in the getter and deleter methods, everything worked fine, but I don’t really get why.I looked at the documentation but I don’t really understand this :
"Name mangling is helpful for letting subclasses override methods without breaking intraclass method calls.” When I get the recursion error I reckon that something is being broken, but it doesn’t seem to me.Follow my reasoning:

1. I define the attribute which is goint to be stored in a dictionary
2. I modify that attribute using self.attribute_name
   I mean it seems that something is already running when i try to modify the attribute name using my approach.Could someone link the concept of private variables with the property descriptor, because probably that’s where the problem lies.Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.age` is a descriptor with the setter logic `set_age`. `set_age` is called whenever `self.age = ...` is performed.

Since an assignment to `self.age` happens in `set_age`, you get infinite recursion.

Comment: Oh I get it when I call self.age I am implicitly calling self.set_age which is modifying self.age which is calling self.set_age() and that’s why I am getting an infinite recursion.Thanks man, but could you tell me why do I modify self.age when I write self._age.

Comment: @Not_here_to_play I think you understood the problem. I don't quite understand your question about `self._age`, but maybe this helps: the point of `self._age` is to store the age value in a "normal" instance variable that does not run getter or setter logic when accessed (unlike `self.age`).

Comment: @Not_here_to_play so `self.age` calls functions when being accessed or set. These functions may do something with `self._age`, where the actual age value is stored, "hidden" from the user.

Comment: @Not_here_to_play also, this has nothing to do with name mangling, you could use `self.actual_value_here` instead of `self._age`.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, I am going to try to be more explicit: in the setter method I cannot say self.age = some_value, because I would keep calling the attribute which would keep calling the set method(infinite recursion).But when i write self._age = some_value, and then try to print the value (print(obj.age)) I get the value set in the set method.My question is: when I write something like self._age, this means that I am setting the attribute to something without calling the set method any further?I mean when I write self._age = 30, then self.age doesn’t run getter or setter?Sorry

Comment: @Not_here_to_play `self._age` is a normal instance variable that you did not define as a property, so no getter or setter logic is run when you get or set it. Rename `self._age` to `self.the_numeric_age_value` in your head. It's completely decoupled from `self.age`, you just happen to access/set in the body of `get_age` or `set_age`.

Comment: Man, I am extremely sorry but I am dumb as fuck.So let me recap my stupid reasoning.1. When I call the __init__ method, I am creating a dictionary which is going to store the attribute (self.age) and the value I set to it. 2. When I run the set method , I create self._age which  is going to have a new value but, as you said, self._age is decoupled, so there is no set or get method attached to it.3.

Comment: But the thing that I don’t understand is: if i create an instance and write instance.age = 30, then I am calling the set method which is going to set a new property self._age =30.But how on earth do i get self._age and not self.age when I run print(self.age).

Comment: @Not_here_to_play "how on earth do i get self._age and not self.age when I run print(self.age)" <- by returning `self._age` in `get_age`.

Comment: you’re right man, so basically I am storing a new property self._age which is private so you can’t access it but that’s what runs under the hood.Thanks a lot man and sorry for wasting your time, but I needed to clear my doubt :)

Comment: @Not_here_to_play `_age` is not a property, it's a normal instance variable. If it was a property like `age`, it would have its own setters and getters.

Comment: Yeah, you’re right. I got confused.Thanks man :)

Comment: @Not_here_to_play you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this to avoid name clashes.

```
class Employer:

    def __init__(self, age, name):
        self.__age = age
        self.__name = name
    
    @property
    def age(self):
        return self.__age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, value):
        if value > 30:
            raise ValueError("Our company doesn't want old people")
        self.__age = value

    @age.deleter
    def age(self):
        del self.__age
```